# Analyzing unity gain feedback of AD8277

Tags: gain

I have the following amplifier; its not large gain so I can't assume virtual ground.
How do I analyze the transfer function of such amplifier?

https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad8277.html

[image]

Comment: A transfer function is expressed as \$\frac{\text{OUT}}{\text{IN}}\$. But the dimensions of each need to be specified. Do you mean the voltage at **OUT** vs the voltage at **VIN** (a pure number without dimension) or do you mean something else? Also. Is this homework? Or something else, entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Start by calculating the voltage at the noninverting input using the ideal op amp assumptions regarding current entering the input terminals.  Then, apply the ideal op amp assumption that the voltages at the input terminals are the same in the presence of negative feedback.  Then solve the rest of the circuit using Kirchoff's laws.